# facebook credits , how to get php back?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

i am using the [facebook credits example](https://github.com/facebook/credits-api-sample/blob/master/index.php) and everything works but this:

```
if ($_GET['order_id'] && $_GET['status']) {
$html = "Transaction Completed! </br></br>"
  ."Data returned from Facebookkkkkk: </br>"
  ."<b>Order ID: </b>" . $_GET['order_id'] . "</br>"
  ."<b>Status: </b>" . $_GET['status'];
} elseif ($_GET['error_code'] && $_GET['error_message']) {
$html = "Transaction Failed! </br></br>"
  ."Error message returned from Facebook:</br>"
  .$_GET['error_message'];
}
```

looks like `$order_id` and `$status` are not passed back.

what i actually need is to get the vars from the form passed back into php so i can put them into a database.

any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get these you generally need to this:

```
$secret = 'YOUR_APP_SECRET';
$request = parse_signed_request($_REQUEST['signed_request'], $secret);
$payload = $request['credits'];
$order_id = $payload['order_id'];
$func = $_REQUEST['method'];
if ($func == 'payments_status_update')
  $status = $payload['status'];
```

Comment: yes, but all that is defined here: https://github.com/facebook/credits-api-sample/blob/master/callback.php and the call to this file is made fron that `index.php` just that `return $data` doesn't happen i guess

Comment: I'd focus on $_REQUEST['method'] and see what if any status FB is posting to you. I'm assuming you are receiving the callback pay request.